# Is there a 'Mercurial Notifier' program that will tell me when an external repository has changed?

Tags: windows, mercurial

There are a few different tools for Subversion that run in the background, pinging the central repository every few minutes, and will alert you if any changes are detected (I'm using Windows 7, but this is true for OS X and Linux as well).

Is there anything like that for Mercurial, that will watch a specific repository and alert me to any changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an extension called [NotifyExtension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/NotifyExtension) that is distributed with Mercurial that can be configured to send email when a repository changes.

Edited to add: If you prefer a local client solution, check out the [Hg Commit Monitor](http://saftsack.fs.uni-bayreuth.de/~dun3/hg-commit-monitor).

Comment: Hm. Not *quite* what I'm looking for, but I'll use it for now (would prefer not to clutter my inbox with change notifications). If I don't get any more responses, I'll mark this as my answer.  --I suppose I could always create a dummy email account just for this purpose, and then use any old email notifier. :)

Comment: Edited to add an alternate option.

Comment: Aha! Now that's pretty much exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this is to have a local tool monitor the repository's RSS (or atom) feed.  Every repo served over hgserve/hgweb/hgwebdir has feeds available and most systems have RSS poller widgets: https://superuser.com/questions/9929/rss-notification-in-system-tray

For example, for the main mercurial repository, you'd configure your feed poller to watch:

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/rss-log